# Save PDF as Arabic Name (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdf-generation

Good Day!

I am saving PDF as English Name _ Employee number i.e. abc_123

But It is not working for arabic name _ employee number

I have tried all ways like meta charset or meta-equip or all additions in headers or top of php files or before queries meta charset etc.

please Guide

I am trying code given below:

```
 mysqli_query($connection,"SET character_set_client=utf8");

      $emp_number =($_POST['emp_number']);
      $owner_name =($_POST['owner_name']);
      $result110= mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM accessories where emp_number='".$emp_number."'");
    while($row19 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result110))  
  { 
    $pdf->SetFont('aealarabiya', '', 15);
    $pdf->Output($row19['owner_name'].'_'.$row19['emp_number'].'.pdf', 'D');
}
```

Above code is fine for English names but not Arabic..It shows __employeenumber for Arabic names like __1234.pdf

Pls guide

Thanks

Comment: Just a tip, don't use `mysql_query`, it's deprecated. Use `mysqli_query` instead, or learn how to use PDO,

Comment: @JaymeBrereton Yes its mysqli I used old format mistakenly. Editted now

Comment: Hmm... not worked :(

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using TCPDF library, if you check the source code of TCPDF class for Output function, you can see that the filename is being sanitized using Regular Expression.

```
if ($dest[0] != 'F') {
    $name = preg_replace('/[\s]+/', '_', $name);
    $name = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\.-]/', '', $name);
}
```

Reading the condition for sanitizing, and from the doc-block of the function, you can use FD: equivalent to F + D option

And your output lines becomes:

```
$pdf->Output($row19['owner_name'].'_'.$row19['emp_number'].'.pdf', 'FD');
```